# Non standard attribute in html element with expression in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html5-video

I have a video directive with the following template:

```
<div class='image-container standard-video' >
   <video  id='post_{{post.id}}_image' 
      class=" post_video pt_animate_heart" 
      width="240" height="240"
      poster="{{post.photo.standard}}"
      title="{{post.description}}" 
      data-fullmode-enable='false'

      preload="none">
      <source src ng-src="{{post.video_url|trustedResource}}" />
    </video>
</div>
```

I have sublimevideo that has a 'poster' attribute that reference to an image. I have problem with this because sublimevideo will try to get the image

```
'{{post.photo.standard}}'
```

from the server instead of understanding it's an expression for angular template. I understand that there is an similar approach solved by angular like ng-src for src attribute. I am looking for similar solution. I really wonder if there any angular directive for this custom element attribute.

Comment: you mean this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352

Comment: Hola @Eduard Gamonal, ng-src in my case does not cause any problem i guess because sublimevideo handle it. the only problem i have is the 'poster' attribute. I want the page wait for angular to get the expression evaluated first and then copy value back to 'poster' attribute like the way ng-src  work.